# Excel VBA - Row by Row Copy with If-Statement Validation

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy, rows

I'm relatively new to VBA and have found myself in a bit of a corner.

The goal:
I want to copy row values from one spreadsheet to another only if specific fields match between the two rows. If the specific fields don't match, I need to skip a row on the copied **TO** workbook and then re-check the copied **FROM** workbook, creating a gap until they match again.

EX: Let the copied **TO** workbook = WB_A
Let the copied **FROM** workbook = WB_B

Both workbooks have a column with ID#, X coordinates, and Y coordinates

WB_A has a static set of ID#'s ranging from -99 to 632 with accompanying X&Y coordinates. 
WB_B has a dynamic set of ID#'s which also fall within the -99 to 632 range but may have gaps in the data (149-161 may be completely missing so that the count goes 147,148,162,163...).

I want to copy values from WB_B to WB_A only if the ID#'s match on the given row, otherwise I want to leave a gap on WB_A until it does match with WB_B.

My Method:

```
Private Sub rowCount()

Dim mstRows As Long
Dim wsMstr As Worksheet, wsPline As Worksheet
Dim wbCompRes As Workbook, wbPline As Workbook
Dim i       As Integer
Dim rowCounter As Integer

'Find end of Master Worksheet rows
Set wsMstr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Wkst")
wsMstr.Activate
mstRows = Worksheets("Master Wkst").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'If statment to check if column a1 in Master Wkst = Column b2 in pline file
'If true, copies rows into Master Wkst, If false, skips row
rowCounter = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 4 To mstRows
    If wsMstr.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Workbooks("20170210_intersect_pline_transect_singlept.dbf") _
       .Worksheets(1).Cells(rowCounter, 2) Then
    Else
        Workbooks("20170210_intersect_pline_transect_singlept.dbf").Activate
        Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(rowCounter, 4), Cells(rowCounter, 5)).Copy
        wsMstr.Activate
        wsMstr.Cells(i, 6).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Currently, I have the code so that it skips the first gap in the data, and then fills out until it gets to the second, gap. My trouble is in cycling through WB_A's non-matching rows while holding WB_B on the same row until it can be matched up with WB_A.

Right now, I have rowCount=4 as a static field, and I know this will be what needs to change, but I am unsure how to change it to make the code function as intended.

I've included links the Pertinent Excel files 
Note: WB_A = Computation_results2017
WB_B = 20170210_Pline....

[Computation_results2017](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12HlCcBuEsl7wZHP29ds9AJzifpjq1HAb)

[20170210_Pline...](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12JtJ3YNDubUyByI9eeXIc1upBw0hpk6Y)

Additionally, any other tricks which might make my code more succinct are welcome!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: At first glance, the IF statement ELSE part is the same as the IF statement THEN part? so I'm going to say you don't need an IF THEN ELSE, you just need IF THEN, and you just need the test for '=' to include all the lines in your ELSE part under your THEN part. So you will never set the rowcounter to 4 in your loop. Also to make it more efficient look up not activating and selecting sheets.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! 
Are you suggesting I just get rid of the second IF statement and simply use an ELSE since it will accomplish the same thing? 
I am pretty new to coding, so I just want to make sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: Almost. From the code you amended above after my statement, get rid of the line/word ELSE.